# How to check if proxy connection is socks4/5 Python Flask

Tags: python, flask, proxy

I'm trying to make a simple program that checks if a connection (to localhost) is HTTP, Socks4 or Socks5.
(I mean connection in the sense of a proxy connection)

```py
import waitress
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def use_proxy():
    # check proxy connection type as string
    return string

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Serving server on 8888.")
    waitress.serve(app, host="localhost", port=8888)
```

How can I get this string?, I'm guessing it could be through the headers.

Comment: Socks4 and Socks5 operate on TCP & UDP/TCP respectively. They have no knowledge of HTTP or any other OSI layer 7 protocols. Meaning from your servers perspective it doesn't know if the client is a Socks server communicating to it or if its the client itself.

Comment: In such case, how do websites like Proxyscrape (https://www.proxyscrape.com/free-proxy-list) check if their proxies are Socks4/5? (@TeddyBearSuicide)

Comment: Do you mean how does the website know if a proxy that is listed is using either Socks4 or Socks5?

Comment: Yes, @TeddyBearSuicide.

Comment: If it's a volunteer's proxy then they might ask them to specify what socks version it is so that it can be posted properly. Or two they connect to each socks server and the first request that the server returns contains its version number. Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS#SOCKS4

Comment: @TeddyBearSuicide I've seen the "VER" variable, how can I access this through Flask?

Comment: You can't. That is something the client sends to the Socks proxy and then the socks proxy sends the recipient a regular request. That VER is a TCP packet that is only used between the socks proxy and its client. Not the recipient.

Comment: Ok, I think I'll try to manually check through each type using Requests. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Im not sure how that works but good luck.